# Blackberry How to Block the Screen From Tapping When Status.Show Invoked?

Tags: blackberry, click, statusbar, tap

I want to block my screen for listening a tap or click when the show.status("Please Wait",2 AnyTimeLimit); is invoked.

Actually I'm sending a hit to a web service and meanwhile I'm displaying a message "Please Wait" with 2 seconds wait. But after those 2 seconds It starts listening the tap/click. How can I block them to listen tapEvent/ClickEvent when displaying message?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make a custom screen that overrides `PopupScreen` for that. In your implementation, you will have to override `onUiEngineAttached`, like so -

```
protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached)
{
    super.onUiEngineAttached(attached);
    if(attached)
    {
        // start server hit thread, which closes the screen when done
    }
}
```

After that, just push the screen using `UiApplication.getUiApplication.pushModalScreen()`. You will want to keep the data you received in a byte array somewhere in the screen's instance which you can retrieve by calling a getter once the screen has been popped.